# What does logging synchronous command do?

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands, logging

Can somebody describe me what does

> logging synchronous

command do ?

Comment: Keeps me sane when running commands on a noisy device!

Comment: Logging synchronous " prevents every logging output from immediately interrupting your console session.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"logging synchronous" prevents every logging output from immediately interrupting your console session.

See command documentation:

"This keeps unsolicited messages and debug output from being interspersed with solicited software output and prompts."

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/fundamentals/command/reference/cf_book/cf_l1.html#wp1020534

Answer (score -1):

prevents from  unsolicited message

Comment: That is not even close to what it does. If you believe otherwise, then please expand on your answer and provide backup to your conclusion.

Comment: You really need to provide more than a four word answer. This is more comment than answer. (and looks like the output of a translation)

Answer (score -2):

It is for disable synchronization of unsolicited messages and debug output